# Check All the checkboxes in a table when a particular checkbox is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, html-table

I am dynamically adding checkboxes using tr and td to a table this way.

```
var arr=[1,2,3];

                var trtest = "<tr>";
                trtest = trtest +"<tr><td><input type='checkbox' onclick=onAllCheckBoxClick('" + arr+ "') class = 'all' id ='all'>All</td></tr>";

$.each(arr, function(i, tmp) {
                    trtest = trtest +"<tr><td><input type='checkbox' onclick=onCheckBoxClick('" + this+ "','" + arr+ "') class = 'all' id ='"+tmp+"'/>"+tmp+"</td></tr>";
                });
```

This code is working And i am getting 4 checkboxes this way,

```
All
    1

    2

    3
```

Here,  when I try to check All  checkbox then all the other checkboxes in the same table 1,2,3 have to be selected.

I tried adding this click event to All checkbox.

```
function onAllCheckBoxClick(arr){
        var checked = $('#all').attr('checked');
        if(checked =="checked") {
            $.each(arr.split(","), function(i, tmp) {
                    $('#'+tmp).attr('checked',true);
            }); 
        }

}
```

Issue is when I check All it is only checking 3 (i.e, last checkbox) in the same table, where 1,2 remained un-checked.

But I want all 1,2,3 checkboxes to be checked when I check All checkbox.

Can anyone help me in this issue?

Comment: `$('input:checkbox').prop('checked',true)` <---- check all checkbox as you like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
 $('#mainChkBox').change(function(){
     $(':checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <th><input type='checkbox' id = 'mainChkBox'/>Click here<th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr>  <td><input type='checkbox'/><td></tr>
    
   <tr>  <td><input type='checkbox'/><td></tr>
    
   <tr>  <td><input type='checkbox'/><td></tr>
    
   <tr>  <td><input type='checkbox'/><td></tr>
    
   <tr>  <td><input type='checkbox'/><td></tr>
    
   <tr>  <td><input type='checkbox'/><td></tr>
    
   <tr>  <td><input type='checkbox'/><td></tr>
    
  </tbody>
  <table>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```js
$(function(){
    $("#master").on("click",function(event){
        $(":checkbox").attr('checked', true);
    });
});
```

```html
<a href="#" id="master">Check All</a>
<input type="checkbox"/>
<input type="checkbox"/>
<input type="checkbox"/>
<input type="checkbox"/>
<input type="checkbox"/>
```

Comment: You can check here how dynamically added checkbox get selected https://jsfiddle.net/c7280yxj/2/

Answer (score 0):

Just other way to do it

```
$('#all').toggle(
    function() { 
        $(':checkbox').attr('checked','checked'); 
    },
    function() { 
        $(':checkbox').removeAttr('checked'); 
    }
);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/n3huxo8s/